# Print specific string in a line after matched word in bash

Tags: regex, bash, grep, cat

Situation
There is a file called test that consists on the following text:

```
this is the first line
version=1.2.3.4
this is the third line
```

How can i print via bash only:

```
1.2.3.4
```

Note: I want always to print until end of line what is after `"version="` not searching for `1.2.3.4`
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU `grep` :

```
grep -Po '^version=\K.*'
```

`-P` enables PCRE regex, `-o` is used to only display what is matched rather than whole lines and the `\K` meta-character specifies not to display what precedes.

Using `sed` :

```
sed -n 's/^version=\(.*\)/\1/p'
```

`-n` disables auto-printing, then the substitution command will replace the "version=[...]" line by only its end through a capturing group. The substitution is only effective on the second line, which trigger the `p` instruction to print the (transformed) line.

Comment: And to make sure in case the string "version=" is hidden somewhere else, it might make sense to use ^version to look for occurences at the beginning of the line

Comment: @Olli right, edited. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
grep version file | cut -d\= -f2
```

Comment: No need to escape `=` AFAIK, it has no special meaning neither for `bash` nor `cut`